# JQuery 960 fixed / fluid switch?

Tags: jquery, css, 960.gs

I'm trying to create a jQuery function which allows a page to switch from fixed to a fluid grid programmatically. So far I haven't been able to get anything working as everything is separated in its own class.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a grid container "div" that by default uses, say, fixed layout: `<div id="gridContainer">`.  Define all of your contained classes based on that fixed container.

`#gridContainer .foo { ... }`  and so on.

Next, define a class "fluid" for "gridContainer."  Now redefine your styles for fluid layout:

`#gridContainer.fluid .foo { ... }` and so on.

Now, you can use jQuery to add or remove the "fluid" class from "gridContainer," thus switching out the defined styles.

Comment: Even better, just use something that's already in your markup: `<body>`. Then just drop the `#gridContainer` qualifier.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought of changing the stylesheet on the fly?

http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml

Comment: I think this jQuery switcher looks a lot more concise. http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/switch-css-stylesheets-using-jquery.html